# Android Google Maps Api, убрать маркеры с одним условием

Tags: android, google-maps-api, карты

Очень долго думаю и не могу понять, как реализовать.

У меня есть карта с маркерами. Маркеры я получаю с сервера. 
Возникла следующая ситуация.

**Пример**

1 запрос: Получаю 10 маркеров которые передал мне сервер. Я их добавляю в HashMap и наношу на карту. 
2 запрос: Получаю уже 8 маркеров из существующих 10 маркеров. 
Вопрос, как объяснить программе, чтобы он убрал с карты 2 несуществующих маркеров?

Запросы с сервера принимаю в виде JSON и обрабатываю в цикле.

Мои код цикла ответа от сервера. Используется ретрофит

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++){

    Marker busMarker;
    int marker_id = response.body().get(i).getId();
    double lat = response.body().get(i).getWarningLat();
    double lon = response.body().get(i).getWarningLon();


    if (mHashMap.containsKey(marker_id)){
        Marker marker = mHashMap.get(marker_id);
        marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lon));
    } else {
        busMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)));
        mHashMap.put(marker_id, busMarker);
    }
```

Надеюсь я максимально понятно объяснил.Пожалуйста помогите вариантами, а то я в тупике

Comment: попробуй перед добавлением маркеров удалить старые и нанести новые.

Comment: Это был бы хороший вариант, но у меня несколько HashMap которые нанесены на карту, и если удалить с карты все маркеры, то я потеряю маркеры которые мне нужны но не добавляются в этом цикле.

Comment: Пройдите в цикле по всем установленным маркерам и если какого-то нет в новой мапе - удаляйте.

Comment: Добавил код для ясности. @eugeneek пройтись циклом внутри цикла или каК?

Comment: Не внутри конечно. Отдельным циклом. Грубо говоря первый проход - удаляете маркеры которых больше нет. Второй проход - добавляете новые. Или можно подумать и как-то сделать это одним проходом.

Comment: @eugeneek Дело в том что сервер мне не сообщает каких маркеров больше нет, а сообщает только маркеры которые есть. И надо как то сказать программе вот эти добавь, все остальное удали )

Comment: вам сервер что даёт? координаты? держите в своей паме пары "LatLng' - "Marker" (ссылка которую вам даёт карта при установке маркера) и потом при получении новых карт идёте по координатам из мапы и смотрите у каких координат нет совпадений и для них удаляете маркер с карты.